# Reasonable file size for streaming video?

Tags: streaming, video, rtmp

I currently have some video files ranging from 2 - 3 hours that I'd like to stream over RTMP/HLS. I'm wondering if there are any best practices to ensure smooth streaming, for example:

Is there a best ratio for file-size/duration when streaming?

Is it better to break a video of several hours into smaller segments and then stream those individually rather than streaming a single file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the video for streaming would be certainly pointless. You should think in terms of audio and video bit-rates instead of filesizes, when talking about streaming video. And this depends on the target devices you want to stream to (for mobile devices, you should use very small resolutions and bitrates), your available upstream bandwidth, and the amount of users you want to support simultaneously. Then the RTMP protocol will take care of splitting the video file into very small fragments for transmission.